# Recreating a Duplicate iPhone Project with Interface Builder Errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Due to some extraneous errors in a previous XCode project that wouldn't allow my iPhone app to run on the iPhone, I had to take all the code and files from what we'll call Project1 and build a new project called Project2.

I then filled Project2 with all the same files, not changing any code.

Next I had to recreate the Interface Builder files. As far as I can tell, this was done with the exact same classes declared in all the IB objects.

However, when I build Project2, it only shows a visible black screen and doesn't display the app.

The one difference I have found between the two projects is that in Project2's Interface Builder, the ToolbarController outlet is not even available for the view, and it is in Project1. I am assuming the lack of connecting the File View to ToolbarController is the problem.

Why is ToolbarController (as shown below) not available and how do I fix this difference?

Below are two screenshots. The first is Project1 and the second is Project2. :

[alt text http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/8296/picture1xne.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/8296/picture1xne.png)
[alt text http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/4194/picture3to.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/4194/picture3to.png)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got the "File Owner" (or the "Toolbar View") set to the wrong class. Interface Builder doesn't see any outlets or actions in the classes you have set currently.